# IVsEditorAdaptersFactoryService.CreateVsTextViewAdapter throws an object null reference

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, sdk, visual-studio-sdk

I'm trying to create a `IVsTextViewAdpater` with the `IVsEditorAdaptersFactoryService` but when I call `CreateVsTextViewAdapter` it throws an object null reference:

```
    var editorFactory = componentModel.GetService<IVsEditorAdaptersFactoryService>();
    var serviceProvider = (Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IServiceProvider)this;
    var view = editorFactory.CreateVsTextViewAdapter(serviceProvider);
```

'this' is a `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package` implementation.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this [post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/6995ed63-754d-4690-9ecb-5dea34f8207d/)

Comment: Does anyone know what the post used to say? The link is broken now. Next time, please provide a complete answer.